# AxShockwaveFlash appearing as a white box on Windows XP Embedded from a C# winform

Tags: c#, .net, axshockwaveflash

I have created an app in C# .Net 2.0 that uses the AxShockwaveFlash object to display youtube videos given from the youtube API. The object itself works fine on the PC I am doing the development (normal Windows XP) but as soon as I put it on our release machines  (XP Embedded) the shockwave object just appears as a white screen.

I have added the following:

Registry settings:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Macromedia\FlashPlayerPlugin]
"Path"="C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\Macromed\\Flash"
"Version"="11.1.102.55"
"PlayerPath"="C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\Macromed\\Flash\\NPSWF32.dll"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Macromedia\FlashPlayerPlugin\Components]
"Main"="1"
```

Adding the flashplayer.xpt file to the location specified and the NPSWF32.dll to the same place as well. This hasn't changed anything but I am stuck and have no real idea what to do. Anything I have missed?

Comment: Well I would expect your problem is that file if for the netscape plugin version of flash, you need to install the ActiveX version for it to work.

Comment: That cannot be nearly enough.  Use SysInternals' ProcMon tool to see what the Flash installer does.  Pay attention to files getting copied and registry entries getting written.  Given that this is Windows Embedded, you'd better also check what Windows components it uses at runtime.  You might have missed some in the builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested we were missing a few files that the object required in order to run, unfortunately I don't have a list of them to hand at the minute, will have a look for the specific names if requested.